# Passing reference type parameters to Aspects

Tags: postsharp

I have created an Aspect to handle database transactions. I wanted to pass a reference type object to this aspect. This object contains properties which tells about the connection status and connection details.( db name, connection open, transaction status etc).

I was able to pass parameters such as bool, int. But I was not able pass reference types, by which i can use the same instance of the object in the aspect as well.

Please suggest the way to procced.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to pass a class or struct to a constructor argument of a custom attribute, or to assign a class or struct to a field or property of a custom attribute.

Unfortunately this is not possible because of limitations of custom attributes in .NET.

Comment: Thank you Gael., Is there any other way to achieve this, so that i can use the instance object in the aspect.

Comment: The problem is not to use reference types in aspects but to assign the value when you instantiate the custom attribute. You can just use primitive types (int, string, ...), enums, Type, and arrays.